# Highlighting data change in TIBCO Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

This is my first post here, so please forgive me if I fail at etiquette or clarity somewhere along the way.

I am working on a POC dealing with highlighting data in Table visualisation within Tibco Spotfire  which will allow a user to see data which has been added or updated in the table after reloading the table data into Spotfire.
I am relatively new to Spotfire so don't have experience in Scripting,Kindly Help, how to approach this problem?

Suppose i have a table visualisation built on table from database, the next time I open the viz. the underlying data table is reloaded. I want any change in the column of underlying data table to be highlighted.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have edited the question, kindly review. @MrPromethee